# função mail do PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando usar a função mail do php para enviar as informações de um formulário pro meu e-mail. Ja procurei em varios foruns, mas não consigo fazer funcionar.
O que esta de errado?

- Não da nenhum tipo de erro ou notice, simplesmente não envia nada, simplesmente volta para o index como se tivesse mandado.
- O Site ja esta hospedado, pois sei que não funciona local;

Obs. a mensagem a ser enviada eu não editei ainda. Mas mesmo assim não envia nada nem para o span.

```
    <?php

include('conexao.php');
    $envia = new conexao;
    $envia->conecta();

/* Verifica qual é o sistema operacional do servidor para ajustar o cabeçalho de forma correta. Não alterar */
if(PHP_OS == "Linux") $quebra_linha = "\n"; //Se for Linux
elseif(PHP_OS == "WINNT") $quebra_linha = "\r\n"; // Se for Windows
else die("Este script nao esta preparado para funcionar com o sistema operacional de seu servidor");


    $emaildestinatario = "meu email";
    $assunto = "Contrato pelo site";

// Passando os dados obtidos pelo formulário para as variáveis abaixo
    $razaosocial        = $_POST['txtRazaosocial'];
    $nomefantasia       = $_POST['txtNomefantasia'];
    $cnjp               = $_POST['txtCnpj'];
    $insce              = $_POST['txtIe'];
    $end                = $_POST['txtEndereco'];
    $numero             = $_POST['txtNumero'];
    $complemento        = $_POST['txtComp'];
    $bairro             = $_POST['txtBairro'];
    $cep                = $_POST['txtCep'];
    $cidade             = $_POST['txtCidade'];
    $estado             = $_POST['txtUf'];
    $email              = $_POST['txtEmail'];
    $telefone           = $_POST['txtTel'];
    $contato            = $_POST['txtContato'];
    $sistema            = $_POST['txtSistema'];
    $usuarios           = $_POST['txtQtdadeusu'];
    $data_envio         = date('d/m/Y');
    $hora_envio         = date('H:i:s');


/* Montando a mensagem a ser enviada no corpo do e-mail. */
$mensagemHTML = '<P>Esse email &eacute; um teste enviado no formato HTML via PHP mail();!</P>';


/* Montando o cabeçalho da mensagem */
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1".$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$quebra_linha;
// Perceba que a linha acima contém "text/html", sem essa linha, a mensagem não chegará formatada.
$headers .= "From: ".$email.$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "Return-Path: " . $email . $quebra_linha;

/* Enviando a mensagem */
mail($emaildestinatario, $assunto, $mensagemHTML, $headers, "-r". $email);


header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

Comment: Por favor, refaça a pergunta de modo que entendamos melhor. O que já foi tentado, qual área de trabalho está usando, qual erro/notice é exibido.

Comment: você esta tentando utilizar ela em servidor de testes localhost ou servidor de produção? se for no local, é preciso instalar um servidor SMTP na maquina local para funcionar ou configurar um smtp no php.ini, se for em produção, consulte o suporte da hospedagem.

Comment: Ele vai redirecionar de todo jeito, seja true ou false, pois você não verificou o retorno da função mail. Tente apenas: mail('example@email.com', 'Assunto', 'mensagem'); sem as variáveis em um arquivo separado.

Comment: Mauro, nem assim do jeito que vc falou envia, fiz um novo arquivo e coloquei no form, mas não enviou.

Comment: Qual o seu servidor?

Comment: Suas configurações no PHP.ini estão corretas ?

Comment: No meu servidor dá a mesma coisa, porém demora cerca de 1 dia pro e-mail chegar. Será que não tá acontecendo o mesmo com você ?

Comment: As configurações estão corretas pois tenho outro formulario funcionando, o que eu peguei como base. E infelizmente não esta chegando mesmo, o enviado ontem não chegou até o momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer funcionar pessoal. Obrigada a todos. O problema estava no form, que brecha rs estava sem a tag name.